# How to give the player coins after he or she watches the reward video?

Tags: swift, chartboost

Im using Chartboost reward videos and Im having trouble figuring out how to give the player 100 coins after the video is done playing. Here is the code for the reward video. Right now its adding the 100 coins even if I x out of the reward video screen. How would I be able to give the coins after the player watches the video?

```
    func loadRewardedVideo() {

    let kChartboostAppID = "appID"
    let kChartboostAppSignature = "appSigniture"

    Chartboost.startWithAppId(kChartboostAppID, appSignature: kChartboostAppSignature, delegate: viewController)

    Chartboost.showRewardedVideo(CBLocationMainMenu)
    Chartboost.cacheRewardedVideo(CBLocationMainMenu)

    if Chartboost.hasRewardedVideo(CBLocationMainMenu) {
        Chartboost.showRewardedVideo(CBLocationMainMenu)

        coins += 200
        totalCoinLabel.text = String(coins)


    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no personal experience with [chartboost](/questions/tagged/chartboost).  However, based off reading their documentation, you need to set up a delegate:

```
Chartboost.startWithAppId(
    "YOUR_CHARTBOOST_APP_ID",
    appSignature: "YOUR_CHARTBOOST_APP_SIGNATURE",
    delegate: self
)
```

And then, your delegate can implement this method to know when a user completely watched a rewarded video:

```
func didCompleteRewardedVideo(location: CBLocation, withReward reward: Int)
```

Comment: When I add coins +=  200 to the didCompleteRewardedVideo I get an error saying "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value"

Comment: @coding22 That's an entirely different, unrelated error.  And without seeing your actual code, I can only guess at the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can add some timer starting with the rewarded video.
If the user returns to the menu(or closes the window) the timer stops.

So, if the timer doesn't reach zero or 30 seconds(whatever your video time is) the player doesn't get coins.

Comment: What if the reward videos are different times?

Comment: If ads are the case here, ads usually have 30 seconds. But you can set the timer to a minimum.
That's what I would do if I were you.
if timespent>=30
coins+=200

Comment: It doesnt go straight to the ad, chartboost asks you to play the reward video first then it plays. I need to set the timer when the user taps yes to show reward video. How would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

In response unexpectedly found nil, if you are using spritekit you must set up a notification to view controller because if it can’t find the value for your coins it will be nil